# How to compile python script to standalone executable windows file that could open without shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script and i want to make a single .exe file for windows.
and run it in the background that's mean do not display shell.

i use :
`pyinstaller --onefile script.py`

but shell displaying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main aim is to make the file run in the background (i.e. without displaying the shell), then you can simply rename the python file to a `.pyw` file, and run it, meaning your file becomes `script.pyw`. You can also use the same `pyinstaller` command on the `script.pyw` file

Comment: i tried it works when i change format to `.pyw`, but when i compile it with `pyinstaller --onefile script.pyw` , exe file displaying shell...

Comment: i just use `pyinstaller -w`